# login using fingerprint authentication with name and password

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, fingerprint, biometrics

I have been trying to implement a login screen that takes a username and password.
Once the user has logged in once I want him to have the ability to login with the device owner's fingerprint.
I was wondering what would be the correct way of handling this login.
I could encrypt the username and password and save those to shared preferences and once a fingerprint that is authorized is entered I will insert the decrypted username and password (I am looking for a solution like ios keychain).
Should I go with this approach or there is a programmatic way to get the names and passwords.

I have already used a library which verifies if the fingerprint is recognized you can see it here: 
https://proandroiddev.com/5-steps-to-implement-biometric-authentication-in-android-dbeb825aeee8

https://github.com/anitaa1990/Biometric-Auth-Sample

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to create an authentication app. Using `SharedPreference` is also a way to create such apps. But, one limit of `SharedPreference` is it can only storage data in limited 
memory space and data is offline (data is stored in local machine and can be lost if you uninstall app). There are many online library for online authentication, if you are learning or developing a small app then I recommend you to use Firebase Authentication. It can help you create user account, authenticate user by mail, phone number,...and also link to real time database, storage on cloud and many other services (if you need). Please refer following link to get more information about firebase!
https://firebase.google.com/docs/?authuser=0

Comment: I dont mind losing the data once the app is uninstalled. I am concerned that I store password in shared prefrences without encryptions. Is there any way to do it (like ios keychain)